# How to move canvas elements?

Tags: javascript, canvas

How to move first element with black fill to mouse cursor? Or just how to move it to my position in event handler?

Javascript:

```
var drawing = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = drawing.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(188, 50, 200, 100);

ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 100);

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    /* How to move rectangle here? */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9545qbo4/1/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not possible on canvas, but your function can do it like this:

```
ctx.clearRect(/* Old rect position */); 
ctx.fillRect(/* New rect position*/);
```

**EDIT:** The same question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975232/how-to-move-rectangle-on-canvas).