# Using html5 Canvas, how do I resolve the issue with saving it as a instance?

Tags: html5-canvas

I have to create rectangles by clicking a button, and after it's created being able to resize it, drag it and change it color by clicking it.
How do I save something that is saved to the canvas and doesn't have its own unique instance?

```js
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "#0000FF";

    context.fillRect(30, 30, 40, 40);
    context.stroke();
    context.save();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move rectangle on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975232/how-to-move-rectangle-on-canvas)

Comment: Yeah for the most part, thats a good post, thankyou